# Marketplace Release - Extension Using External Composer Packages

Tags: magento-1.9, composer, package, marketplace

I'm using some composer packages (like `microsoft/application-insights`) in the extension I've developed and now that I'm trying to submit the extension for technical review I've got a lot of errors for the files from the `vendor` folder.
Is there some documentation about how to approach these cases? I've seen something about shared packages, but I don't think this is my case.

Anyone else has some experience with external packages in your extension? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are submitting the extension with its own vendor directory. If the external dependencies are publicly available, just include them as requirements in `composer.json`. Do not submit `vendor` and `composer.lock` to the marketplace.